# Как при ссылке на страницу лист новостей открывать по айди новость в модальном окне?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`Link.ru#newId1` по примерно такой ссылке, по айди, требуется открывать с листа новостей каждую новость отдельно.

Как это осуществимо в реакте? Именно в Модалке через `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все зависит конкретно от вашей реализации компонентов списка новостей, входных данных. В самом примитивном случае можно сделать что-то вроде такого:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
 state = {
  news: [{
   id: 0,
   title: "News 1",
   detail: "Detail news 1"
  },
  {
   id: 1,
   title: "News 2",
   detail: "Detail news 2"
  },
  {
   id: 2,
   title: "News 3",
   detail: "Detail news 3"
  }
  ],
  modalOpen: false,
  modalContent: -1,
 }
 openDetail = (event, id) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.setState({
   modalContent: id,
   modalOpen: true,
  })
 }
 closeModal= ()=>{
  this.setState({
   modalOpen:false,
  })
 }
 openModal = () => {
  if(this.state.modalOpen && this.state.modalContent!==-1){
   return (<div className="modal">{this.state.news[this.state.modalContent].detail}<div onClick={this.closeModal} className="close">&times;</div></div>);
  }else{
   return null;
  }
 }
 printList = () => {
  return (this.state.news.map((item,key) => {
   return ( < div key = {key} > < a onClick = {
    (event) => this.openDetail(event, key)
   }
   href = {`Link.ru#${key}`}
   className = "list" > {item.title}
   </a>
   </div > )
  }));
 }
 render() {
  return ( < div > {this.printList()} {this.openModal()} < /div>)
 }
}
ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.modal {
  background: #ggg;
  position: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height:100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо а как вот будет ссылка с айди 2323 по ней снаружи при переходе что бы модалка так же была открыта, как это сделать?

Comment: @Badzillazavr не совсем понял вопрос. Допустим у ссылки id=2323, а дальше что нужно сделать?